# Scalar Valued UDF with MAX() Cannot Return Data To Client

Tags: t-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a UDF that can be abstracted as something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[test] (
...
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    
return SELECT Max(...SUBSTRING([a], 1, 2) ... )
FROM tbl
WHERE [col] = 'value'

END
```

However, I'm getting the error:

> Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client

I also cannot simply return the value of Max() as in

```
...
return Max(...SUBSTRING([a], 1, 2) ... )
...
```

because then it complains that [a] is an Invalid Column Name.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: The error message is telling you the truth: You would need to assign the `SELECT` value to a variable and return it from there.
You have some other problems here, though. Scalar UDFs are notorious for poor performance and you appear to be trying to return an `INT` from inside a string-type without any type conversion.

Comment: 1) Sorry, yes I do have a TRYCAST() in there, I just didn't want to bog down the original post with implementation details.

2) So you're saying to do something like
`DECLARE @temp int;
set @temp = SELECT Max(...SUBSTRING([a], 1, 2) ... )
return @temp`
I tried this and it's throwing an error as well with error message `Invalid column name [a]`
@paneerakbari

Comment: Is `[a]` the name of a column that exists in `tbl`?

Comment: Yes, it is in tbl. I'm using [a] as part of my substring call @paneerakbari

Answer (score 0):

Scalar user defined function expects output variable to be declared.
Declare a variable of datatype INT to store output and then assign value to be returned to that variable.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[test] (
...
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
declare @output INT 

SELECT @output = Max(...SUBSTRING([a], 1, 2) ... )
FROM tbl
WHERE [col] = 'value'


return @output


END
```